Как получить чистый вебхук от телеграма Python
у меня есть бот на aiogram 2.25.2, мне нужно при старте бота получить json который присылает телеграм боту, важно то, что мне нужен именно исходный вебхук от телеги, а я могу получить лишь его часть, которую беру из объекта Message
@dp.message_handler(commands=['start'])
async def start(message: types.Message):
     print(message)


Сделайте самостоятельно запрос на https://api.telegram.org/bot<ваш_токен>/getUpdates
